# Save multiple Select statements to a file (.txt, .csv) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

How can we export or save multiple select statements in SQL Server?

As for example, if we have 3-4 select statements, how can we export or print them to a single `.txt` or `.csv` file?

In mysql we have

```
select * from person INTO OUTFILE 'c/person.txt'
```

to print to a file, but what is the equivalent for this in SQL Server?
Is there any SQL query using which I can come to a solution?

Comment: [8 Ways to Export SQL Results To a Text File](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Export/147145/)

Comment: `bcp`, `sqlcmd`, SSIS, to name a few.

Comment: I have the select statements in a stored procedure, from which i want to export the select statement by giving a option in the procedure to print the required fields/statements

Comment: Use DBeaver - has ability to export as csv. And it's cross SQL vendor compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the data output grid and select `Save Results As...`

If you want to export the results of the query without viewing the data grid you can got to `Query->Query Options` confirm your settings and then press `Ctrl + Shift + F` to export results to file.

[Export CSV Data](https://dabblingwithdata.wordpress.com/2015/06/11/exporting-csv-data-from-sql-server-management-studio/)

Comment: I know to export it manually but how to print it by running a stored procedure